# How to run AUTOMOC, AUTOUIC and AUTORCC every time project is build?

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, visual-studio-2019

I have a C++ Project in which I use Qt library. I have cmake build system and I use Visual Studio 2019. Currently I have the below in CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
```

this only triggers the above whenever a source file is touched. But whenever I use designer and make changes in the ui and build the project, nothing compiles and everything remains same. I have to manually touch any random source file to build the project. I am new to cmake and I tried to follow the documentation (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_target) but found it harder to implement. If someone could guide me how to run the above every time build is triggered that would be really helpful. Thank you